# VBA getelementsbytagname issue

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,

I'm attempting to extract HTML table information and collate results on en excel spreadsheet.

I'm using the `getelementsbytagname("table")(0)` function to extract the HTML table info, which has worked well. Can someone please tell me what is the significance of the `(0)` after the table?

Also, I have an instance where an opened webpage does not have any table information to process (I don't know this until the page is opened), this leads to an error in my code as I try to initialize my data array to the table dimensions. Is there a way of extracting a result from `getelementsbytagname("table")(0)`, I've tried:-

```
If (iDom.getelementsbytagname("table")(0) = 0) Then
```

but this returns a run time error.
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First add reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)` and to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`:

[image]

Then the `Object Explorer` is your friend:

[image]

So `getElementsByTagName` returns `IHTMLElementCollection` which has property `length`. When on the page some elements with specific tag name are found then `length` is greater then zero. HTH

```
Dim tables As IHTMLElementCollection
Set tables = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
If tables.Length > 0 Then
    Dim table As HTMLTable
    Set table = tables.item(0)
    ' Because item is the default property of IHTMLElementCollection we can simplyfy
    Set table = tables(0) ' this is the same as tables.item(0)
End If
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks dee. When I placed a watch on doc.getElementsByTagName("table") I could see the IHTMLElementCollection but I wasn't sure how to access the elements.

Many thanks again, where would we be without fantastic resources and fantastic people like yoursleves!

Answer (score 0):

In VBA the appended `(0)` refers to the first element of an array (assuming an [Option Base 0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251511.aspx)). Here is a short example:

```
vArr = Array("element 1", "element 2", "element 3")
Debug.Print v(1)
```

<sub>The above code should return `element 2` as the second element of a zero-based array.</sub>

So, `getelementsbytagname("table")(0)` refers to the first element of that table. Yet, if the "table" is not found then there is no array to get from that table and getting the first element from that array (by appending `(0)`) yields an error.

Instead you should test if there is actually a table by that name (before trying to access the array of elements within that table) like so:

```
If (iDom.getelementsbytagname("table") = 0) Then
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response Ralph, much appreciated. 

I had tried variations on 'If (iDom.getelementsbytagname("table") = 0) Then' but I was getting the same runtime error. After putting in a watch on iDom.getelementsbytagname("table")(0) when I knew there was no table, I saw that the return type was a Variant/Object, so I can get around this by testing 'If iDom.getelementsbytagname("table")(0) Is Nothing Then', which seems to work. 

Thanks again