# How to retrieve specific information from XML type document

Tags: excel, xml, vba, nodes

I`m working on a VBA macro in Excel, to gather information from a CNC program code.
So far, I have gotten Material type, thickness, x & Y sizes, and qty used.

I`m trying to get the 'cutting length' now - so I can use it in costing calculations.

Here is the XML code segment :

```
<Info num="6" name="Tools">
      <MC machine="psys_ETN_5">
        <Tool name="TN901" length="16262.96209" time="53.72817301" cutoutArea="8138.657052"/>
      </MC>
    </Info>
```

There are lots of 'Info' lines.
There may be more than one 'Tool' line, but I`m only after anything from line with 'TN901'.

The data I`m trying to capture is the value of 'Length="######.##"'

I`ve captured everything else I need from code like this :

```
<Material>316</Material>
      <SheetX>2000</SheetX>
      <SheetY>1000</SheetY>
      <Thickness>3</Thickness>
</Material>
```

using code like this:

```
    For Each nodemat In XMLDataDrg.SelectNodes("//Material")
        Matl = nodemat.Text
        Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("H" & RowA).Value = Matl
    Next
    For Each nodesht In XMLDataDrg.SelectNodes("//Thickness")
        Thk = nodesht.Text
        Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("I" & RowA).Value = Thk
    Next
```

But that type of code does not get the cutting length.

Any help please ? :)

Thanks

Simon

Comment: Have you tried something like `getElementsByTagName`? [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907223/vba-getelementsbytagname-issue])

Answer (score 0):

Thickness is saved as XML element in your example.
The length is stored as an XML attribute.
(see https://www.xmlfiles.com/xml/xml-attributes/)

To read an XML attribute please have a look at: 
[Read XML Attribute VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297068/read-xml-attribute-vba)

Based on the code presented there you should be able to solve your issue with:

```
'Include a reference to Microsoft XML v3
Dim XMLDataDrg As DOMDocument30
Set XMLDataDrg = New DOMDocument30
XMLDataDrg.Load ("C:\...\sample.xml")

'...

Dim id As String
id = XMLDataDrg.SelectSingleNode("//Info/MC/Tool").Attributes.getNamedItem("length").Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an xpath to restrict to `Tool` elements with attribute `name` having value `TN901` then loop all the attributes and write out. I am reading your XML from a file on desktop.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    With xmlDoc
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .async = False

        If Not .Load("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.xml") Then
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
        End If
    End With
    Dim elem As Object, attrib As Object

    For Each elem In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Tool[@name='TN901']")
       For Each attrib In elem.Attributes
           Debug.Print attrib.nodeName, attrib.Text
       Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Result:

[image]